# Python code producing decimal values for int fields

Tags: python, teradata

I am trying to retrieve data from teradata database and save it in flatfile. But when I run the SQL query in SQL editor everything looks as expected. But when I run the same query from Python script the integer fields are converted to floating point decimals with .0. Can anybody suggest me how to get rid of this.
Here is my connection code in python

```
uda = teradata.UdaExec(appName = "Sample", version = "1.0", logConsole=False)
self.conn = uda.connect(method = 'odbc', system = self.db, username = self.user, password = self.pwd)
result =  pd.read_sql_query(sql, self.conn)
```

Comment: If you have any missing values (`NULL`) in any column, the column data type is changed to float. If this is your case, you can either ignore the `.0` or eliminate the missing values and cast the column back to int with `.astype(int)`.

Comment: @DYZ Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to fix this issue by adding coerce_float = False parameter in the read_sql_query method.